# Using the Picard Iteration Method on $y' = -\sin(y) +1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$y' = -\sin(y) +1, y(0) = 0$
I'm not sure entirely how to use Picard's iteration method to solve this problem for 4 iterations. Could someone walk me step-by-step through this problem?

My work:

- Zeroth Iteration: f<sub>0</sub> = 0
- First Iteration: f<sub>1</sub> = x
- Second Iteration: f<sub>2</sub> = x + cos(x) -1

After this point the iterations get messy, but for some reason the answer I get in the textbook is [image]

How did they come to that answer?

Comment: What happens when you follow the Picard iteration procedure?

Comment: You may find this helpful : https://users.math.msu.edu/users/seal/teaching/f09/picard_iteration.pdf

Comment: Did you succeed at the first two steps? After that it gets indeed slightly complex if you do not reduce it to truncated power series or similar simplifications.

Comment: I added some clarification now

Answer (score 1):

I will show how to get $\phi_3(t)$ since $\phi_4(t)$ is the same step. First note that $\phi_2(t)$ is the Taylor expansion of $\cos t + 1 -t.$

To get $\phi_3$ we have to integrate

$$\int_{0}^{t} -\sin(\cos t + 1 - t) +1.$$ We use the Taylor expansion in the argument of $\sin$ and also expand $\sin$ as a Taylor series. Then we want to find all combinations of products of the Taylor expansion of $\cos t$ such that the power is less than $t^5$ (as we then integrate to get terms of powers $t^6$ and we are ignoring anything beyond that. The Taylor expansion of $\sin$ contains powers 1, 3, and 5, so we find that number of combinations in the terms of $\phi_2$ such that the power is at most 5. The ways are

1: $t, t^2, t^4, t^6$

3: $ttt, 3ttt^2, 3tt^2t^2$

5: $ttttt$

The coefficients are the combinatorial factors. So we have to integrate

$$1 -(t-t^2/2! + t^4/4! -t^6/6!) + 1/3!(t^3 -3t^2\cdot t^2/2! +3t \cdot t^2/2! \cdot t^2/2!) -t^5/5!$$

When you simplify this you get

$$ 1 - t +t^2/2! + t^3/3! - 7t^4/4! + 14t^5/5!$$

which integrated gives you $\phi_3(t)$. The same steps are used for $\phi_4$.